# Executing Function in background in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to execute a function called alarm in background while function called clock is running. this is my alarm function. As code inside is complex I am only putting an example.

```
def Alarm():
     while True:
            current_time = dt.datetime.now().time()
            if timetable[0] == current_time:
                  print("Its time")
                  break

clock()
Alarm()
root.mainloop()
```

The Function isn't executing in background but it executes first and then GUI is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html):

```py
import threading

# Your Alarm definition

alarm_thread = threading.Thread(target=Alarm)
main_thread = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)

alarm_thread.start()
main_thread.start()
```

The functions will now run concurrently, but be aware that it will be tricky to manage interactions between the two. I don't know how the `clock` function is defined or how you want it to run, but you can easily modify the code to make that one run concurrently too.

Comment: Thanks for info. Clock function is simple digital clock function using time module and a bit modification on GUI

Comment: Running `mainloop()` in a child thread may cause problem.

Comment: @acw1668 huh, I wasn't aware of that... how so?

Comment: `tkinter` don't recommend you call some `tcl/tk` command on another thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `after()` to replace the while loop:

```
def alarm():
    current_time = dt.datetime.now().time()
    if current_time >= timetable[0]:
        print("It's time")
    else:
        # check again 1 second later
        root.after(1000, alarm)

clock()
alarm()
root.mainloop()
```